# Reverse file lines in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to reverse saved file lines backwards and add to every line a string then save it to new text file.
Input :

```
A
Z
E
R
```

Output:

```
Exemple/R
Exemple/E
Exemple/Z
Exemple/A
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! What are your thoughts on how to solve this? Please show your current code in order to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

After view the edit question with new format like

```
A
Z
E
R
```

Then you can

- Reversed the string using `[::-1]`.
- Split by new line using `split("\n")`.
- And then loop through it and print the value you want in this way:

```py
txt = '''A
Z
E
R'''
txt = txt[::-1]
split = txt.split("\n")
for x in split:
    print("Exemple/"+x)
```

Also, if you want read and write into a file, then you can:

- Open a new file
- Use `readlines()` to get text as string by lines
- Do the same as before to get the reversed text
- Write into a new file

```py
with open("your_file_to_read") as f:
    txt = f.readlines()
    txt = txt[::-1]
    with open("your_file_to_write", "w") as outf:
        for x in txt:
            outf.write("Exemple/"+x)
```

Comment: Heads up, the OP intended the inputs to be on separate lines, not space separated (they just didn't understand how to make the preformatted text with line breaks appear properly in Markdown). I've fixed the formatting on the question; you might want to adjust your answer a titch to match.

Comment: Updated answer, thanks. I didn't noticed about the format.

Comment: Thanks @J.F. it works like a charm i only added "\n" for the last line

Comment: You are welcome. Also if the issue has been resolved mark the answer as accepted is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### The Conditions

From what information you're providing, I'm assuming you mean the following:

1. Read from a text file and take in a file line like "A" from the file.
2. Reverse the order of the lines
3. Concatenate an unrelated string to each character of the file line. (ex. "R" --> "Example/R")
4. Create a new text file.
5. Output the new string to the new text file.
6. Repeat for new file line(s) if necessary.

### The Program

With these conditions in mind, I've created a function called line_inverter() that takes the following arguments:

- import_file_name (the name of the file you would like to take data from)
- export_file_name (the new file you'd like to create and export data to)
- prefix_string (the string you'd like to add to the front of each character in a line)

Here's the raw code in Python 3. (If you want to see it in a repo on GitHub instead, click [here](https://github.com/VirdanTheBurden/stackoverflow_coding_help.git))

```py
# inverts file line(s) and writes to a new file
def line_inverter(import_file_name, export_file_name, prefix_string):
    
    # tries to open import file in reading mode
    f1 = open(import_file_name, "r")
    
    # tries to create export file in append mode
    f2 = open(export_file_name, "a")
    
    
    # creates a list with each line in a separate index
    line_list = f1.readlines()
    
    # reverses line order
    line_list.reverse()
    
    # closes import file, since all data is stored in line_list
    f1.close()
    
    
    # loops through line_list to modify individual indices
    for line in line_list:
        
        # strips the "\n" from the string
        line = line.strip("\n")
        
        # concatenates prefix_string and a character from the line_list
        x = prefix_string + line
        
        # appends the line to the new file
        f2.write(x)
        
    # once the loop is finished, close the new file
    f2.close()
```

I'm pretty new at this still, so this is *definitely* not perfect. It works from what I've tested though. Still, if it bricks in any sort of way, let me know, I'd hate to give a faulty program :3

Comment: The ```try``` block makes it such that, if an incorrect parameter type is input for ```import_file_name```, it will continue with the function (after printing some text) - you probably don't want this. Anyway, I'm not sure why you would catch TypeError at all, as that exception is descriptive enough. Also consider learning how to use the ```with``` block: it would make this code's file handling more pythonic. Finally, I wouldn't use the letter ```i``` for a non-index in a ```for``` loop - it looks a little confusing.

Comment: Thank you for telling me! I've removed the statements and let it be. Oh, and I'll be sure to learn that as well, anything to improve! I'll also replace the i with something else, apologies!

Comment: Am getting syntax error at def line_inverter(). i've tried def line_inverter("import_file.txt", "import_file.txt","www./" and def line_inverter(f1, f2,x)  should i import any biblio to handle the fuction def?

Comment: If you want to call a function, you need to write a new line in a python file with the code above and type the following:
`line_inverter("import_file.txt", "export_file.txt", "www./")`, I made it to take from one file, export to another with modified lines. And don't include "def" at the front, that means you're defining (or redefining) a function.